# How to make a thread wait for another's thread results in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait

I have *n* threads executing (an array of threads) and in each one of them I need to make some calculation based on the result of the other threads. How can I, inside a thread, wait until the result of the other threads are ready?

Comment: Sounds like you have a deadlock problem if there are n threads and each wait on n-1 other threads. Is it the case that T1 needs the results from T2 which needs the results from T1?

Comment: Don't do that. Instead, whenever a result is ready, check to see if there's anything else you can do as a result and dispatch that work then. There's no need to have a thread waiting for something to happen to do something, just do something when the thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

There are really dozens of possible answers to this question. The classic one is use locks with condition variables (in Java: `synchronized` + `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()`).

Or use a `Future<T>` or a `CompletableFuture<T>`.

Answer (score -1):

There are two options.

1) Inside your thread that needs to wait for the results you can make it sleep with a while loop.

```
    while(threadResult == null){
             this.sleep(your specified amount of time)
    }
    // When it finally has a value it will continue.
    this.value = threadResult;
```

2) You can make your thread wait until the other notifies it. You need to use a object they both have in common, and you wait and sleep on the other object.

Your thread runs its code, when you need the other results use,

```
    CommonObject.wait();
```

When your other thread completes its operation and updates the results you need you would notify the common object, and the thread waiting will continue its task.

```
    CommonObject.notify();
```